# Gitlab CI forces me to define stages when using multiple include

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a base file .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
include:
  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    file: 'test1.yml'
```

test1.yml:

```
stages:
 -test_stage1

test_stage1:
 stage: test_stage1
 script: //some script
```

it works fine, test_stage1 runs successfully.

Now if I want to include other file as well:

```
include:
  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    file: 'test1.yml'
  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    file: 'test2.yml'
```

test2.yml:

```
stages:
 -test_stage2

test_stage2:
 stage: test_stage2
 script: //some script
```

I get the following error:

> This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: test_stage job: stage
>   parameter should be test_stage2

So I have to add explicitly the stages:

```
    include:
      - project: 'my-group/my-project'
        file: 'test1.yml'
      - project: 'my-group/my-project'
        file: 'test2.yml'
   stages:
      -test_stage1
      -test_stage2
```

And it  works.
Why is that?
  Am I able to somehow just include multiple files and go through all of their stages without declaring them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define your stages so that GitLab CI knows the *sequence* of stages.

See the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages).

> Am I able to somehow just include multiple files and go through all of their stages without declaring them?

Not if you want to have multiple stages.  You need to tell GitLab CI which stage comes first, second etc., so that all the jobs for each stage can be run before going on to the next stage.  That gives us a pipeline.

The default stage is `test`, by the way.  If you don't provide the `stage` attribute for a job, it'll be assigned to the `test` stage.

Comment: But why not gitlab just build the pipeline from the order of the included file's stages?

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  That's now how GitLab CI works.  Once you've declared your stage sequence, GitLab will ensure jobs run in that sequence (stage-wise), regardless of the order in which they appear in your YAML file.